# How to export objects in multiple layes of a PSD to JPEG?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am completely new to Photoshop. I have a PSD file which has multiple layers, and I need to export various images/components from this PSD and export them to JPEG.

Answer (score 2):

You can export all layers by using the following batch tool in Photoshop:

In the menu

**File → Scripts → Export layers to files...**

you can set JPEG at the "file type" option.

This works in CS to CS5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but it didnt work :( For instance, my banner which had text in it, the image was exported but it was without the text. is there a way I could get the banner as a whole. Similarly i  have various components on the page which need to be exported as a whole but are vested in multiple layers. How can i export these images as jpegs?

Comment: Yes that is possible. The thing is with the script that I told you is, that it will export by definition every single layer as an image. If you want to have the text on the banner you will have to merge the text layer with the banner layer.

Comment: highlight both layers -> right click -> and select merge layers.  An other option, if you want to export several components with the script as a jpeg, you have to select all the layers you want combined, make a right click and create a smart object out of them. A smart object is like a layer, but keeps all the members in it intact. hope that helped a bit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Adobe Photoshop CS6 do the following:

1. Select all the layers
2. Right-click and convert into smart objects
3. Go to **File → Script → Image processor**
4. Click Run

And that's it. Job done.